# Neo4j apply order to collect function

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have data as follows

```
node - student
node - exam
Relationship (student)-[:given]->(exam)
```

Here one student has given multiple exams.
I need to fetch last 3 exams of all users

I have done somthing like this -

```
MATCH (s:student)-[:given]->(e:exam)
return id(s) as student_id, s.name as student_name,
collect({exam_id:id(e), mark:e.marks,  exam_date:e.examp_date})
```

It will fetch data for me but, I just need to exam to be ordered by exam_date and there should be limit so that I can get only last 3 exams

I am expecting this to be done in a single query

Please comment here if more explanation is needed.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
MATCH (s:student)-[r:given]->(e:exam)
WITH s,r,e ORDER BY e.exam_date DESC
return id(s) as student_id, s.name as student_name,
collect({exam_id:id(e), mark:e.marks,  exam_date:e.examp_date})[0..3]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your model is not really optimized for such query, you may want to look at linked lists for the exams.

Anyway this is a working query :

```
MATCH (s:student)
MATCH (s)-[:given]->(e:exam)
WITH s, e
ORDER BY e.exam_date
WITH s, collect(e) as exams
return id(s) as student_id, s.name as student_name,
extract(x in exams[0..3] | 
         {exam_id: id(x), mark: x.marks, exam_date: x.examp_date}) as exams
```